# How to get id from rows with unique ids?

Tags: mysql, entity-attribute-value

I have a table like this:

```
id | customer_id | code
-----------------------
1  |  1          | A
2  |  1          | B
3  |  2          | A
4  |  2          | D
5  |  3          | B
6  |  3          | C
6  |  3          | D
```

I need an SQL query that returns all customer ids with codes equal to A and B.  In the above data, this would only be customer_id 1.

If the codes were each their own column, this would be a straightforward query: `SELECT DISTINCT customer_id FROM tablename WHERE code = A AND code = B`.  I can't seem to craft it over multiple rows, however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `GROUP BY customer_id` with a `HAVING` clause:

```
select customer_id
from yourtable
where code in ('A', 'B')
group by customer_id
having count(distinct code) = 2
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/10ff1/1)

If you want to return more data from your table, then you can expand the query to:

```
select *
from yourtable t1
where exists (select customer_id
              from yourtable t2
              where code in ('A', 'B')
                and t1.customer_id = t2.customer_id
              group by customer_id
              having count(distinct code) = 2)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/10ff1/3)

Comment: Thanks!  I was doing a SELECT of nested SELECTs and knew there had to be a better way.

Comment: @Toast happy to help.  FYI, you can use this in a `WHERE EXISTS` if you wanted to return more data from yourtable. See my edit

Answer (score 1):

```
select customer_id
from tablename
where code in ('A', 'B')
group by customer_id
having count(*) > 1
```